# Генерация HTML с изображениями на php (tcpdf)

Tags: pdf, tcpdf, php

С обычным `html` проблем нет! Чуток переделал пример и готово.

А вот как генерировать `PDF` из `HTML` с изображениями?

```
<img src="бла бла бла">
```

Answer (score 1):

используйте метод `WriteHTML()`

Доки: http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#ac3fdf25fcd36f1dce04f92187c621407
Пример: http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_006.phps
Результат: http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_006.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Пример генерации PDF из SVG изображения:

```
$pdf->ImageSVG($file='/home/vipviz00/vipvizitka.in.ua/vv/po/image.svg', $x=15, $y=30, $w='', $h='', $link='http://www.tcpdf.org', $align='', $palign='', $border=1, $fitonpage=false);
```